# Qt events or repaint() function not working

Tags: c++, qt

The key event listener or the function repaint() are not working, I've tried calling paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) directly but it didn't work either, thanks to further answers.

Here's the code:

window.h

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QRectF>

namespace Ui {
class Window;
}

class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Window();

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *  );

private:
    Ui::Window *ui;

    QRectF player;

    QPainter * painter = new QPainter(this);
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

window.cpp

```
#include "window.h"
#include "ui_window.h"

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Window)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    player.setX(0);
    player.setY(0);
    player.setWidth(50);
    player.setHeight(50);
}

Window::~Window()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.drawEllipse(player.x(), player.y(), player.width(), player.height());
}

void Window::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    if(event->type() == Qt::Key_W)
        player.setY(player.y() - 1);
    if(event->type() == Qt::Key_S)
        player.setY(player.y() + 1);
    if(event->type() == Qt::Key_A)
        player.setX(player.x() - 1);
    if(event->type() == Qt::Key_D)
        player.setX(player.x() + 1);
    repaint();   
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "window.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What does not work ? Is anything displayed ? Have you tried adding printf lines in the functions to see if they are called or not ?Be more specific.

Comment: the initial drawings are displayed but pressing the keys don't respond and repaint() is not called or is not working

Comment: Add debugging code to the keyPressEvent. Most probably, it is never called because the widget does not have the keyboard focus. If it is never called, try adding w.setFocus()

Comment: I've done that, didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Window::keyPressEvent`, replace `event->type()` with `event->key()` everywhere.

Also, take a look at the compiler output. I think it should have warned you about comparing `QEvent::Type` with `Qt::Key` objects.